# Use object detection of tensorflow to train my model,the time stamp of the ckpt file has not changed for more than 4 hours

Tags: python, tensorflow, computer-vision, anaconda, object-detection

I use anaconda(python3.6) and tensorflow(1.9.0) on windows 10 to train my model.

I use this command to train the model：

> python model_main.py --pipeline_config_path=training/ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco.config --model_dir=training/  --num_train_steps=500 --alsologtostderr

Anaconda prompt outputs the following information.

[image]
[image]
[image]

And in my model folder, the time stamp of the ckpt files never changed.
[image]

The content in ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco.config likes this:

```
# SSD with Mobilenet v1 configuration for MSCOCO Dataset.
# Users should configure the fine_tune_checkpoint field in the train config as
# well as the label_map_path and input_path fields in the train_input_reader and
# eval_input_reader. Search for "PATH_TO_BE_CONFIGURED" to find the fields that
# should be configured.

model {
  ssd {
    num_classes: 2
    box_coder {
      faster_rcnn_box_coder {
        y_scale: 10.0
        x_scale: 10.0
        height_scale: 5.0
        width_scale: 5.0
      }
    }
    matcher {
      argmax_matcher {
        matched_threshold: 0.5
        unmatched_threshold: 0.5
        ignore_thresholds: false
        negatives_lower_than_unmatched: true
        force_match_for_each_row: true
      }
    }
    similarity_calculator {
      iou_similarity {
      }
    }
    anchor_generator {
      ssd_anchor_generator {
        num_layers: 6
        min_scale: 0.2
        max_scale: 0.95
        aspect_ratios: 1.0
        aspect_ratios: 2.0
        aspect_ratios: 0.5
        aspect_ratios: 3.0
        aspect_ratios: 0.3333
      }
    }
    image_resizer {
      fixed_shape_resizer {
        height: 300
        width: 300
      }
    }
    box_predictor {
      convolutional_box_predictor {
        min_depth: 0
        max_depth: 0
        num_layers_before_predictor: 0
        use_dropout: false
        dropout_keep_probability: 0.8
        kernel_size: 1
        box_code_size: 4
        apply_sigmoid_to_scores: false
        conv_hyperparams {
          activation: RELU_6,
          regularizer {
            l2_regularizer {
              weight: 0.00004
            }
          }
          initializer {
            truncated_normal_initializer {
              stddev: 0.03
              mean: 0.0
            }
          }
          batch_norm {
            train: true,
            scale: true,
            center: true,
            decay: 0.9997,
            epsilon: 0.001,
          }
        }
      }
    }
    feature_extractor {
      type: 'ssd_mobilenet_v1'
      min_depth: 16
      depth_multiplier: 1.0
      conv_hyperparams {
        activation: RELU_6,
        regularizer {
          l2_regularizer {
            weight: 0.00004
          }
        }
        initializer {
          truncated_normal_initializer {
            stddev: 0.03
            mean: 0.0
          }
        }
        batch_norm {
          train: true,
          scale: true,
          center: true,
          decay: 0.9997,
          epsilon: 0.001,
        }
      }
    }
    loss {
      classification_loss {
        weighted_sigmoid {
        }
      }
      localization_loss {
        weighted_smooth_l1 {
        }
      }
      hard_example_miner {
        num_hard_examples: 3000
        iou_threshold: 0.99
        loss_type: CLASSIFICATION
        max_negatives_per_positive: 3
        min_negatives_per_image: 0
      }
      classification_weight: 1.0
      localization_weight: 1.0
    }
    normalize_loss_by_num_matches: true
    post_processing {
      batch_non_max_suppression {
        score_threshold: 1e-8
        iou_threshold: 0.6
        max_detections_per_class: 100
        max_total_detections: 100
      }
      score_converter: SIGMOID
    }
  }
}

train_config: {
  batch_size: 1
  optimizer {
    rms_prop_optimizer: {
      learning_rate: {
        exponential_decay_learning_rate {
          initial_learning_rate: 0.004
          decay_steps: 800720
          decay_factor: 0.95
        }
      }
      momentum_optimizer_value: 0.9
      decay: 0.9
      epsilon: 1.0
    }
  }
  #fine_tune_checkpoint: "PATH_TO_BE_CONFIGURED/model.ckpt"
  #from_detection_checkpoint: true
  # Note: The below line limits the training process to 200K steps, which we
  # empirically found to be sufficient enough to train the pets dataset. This
  # effectively bypasses the learning rate schedule (the learning rate will
  # never decay). Remove the below line to train indefinitely.
  num_steps: 100
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_horizontal_flip {
    }
  }
  data_augmentation_options {
    ssd_random_crop {
    }
  }
}

train_input_reader: {
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path:'data/train.record'
  }
  label_map_path:'data/side_vehicle.pbtxt'
}

eval_config: {
  num_examples: 8000
  # Note: The below line limits the evaluation process to 10 evaluations.
  # Remove the below line to evaluate indefinitely.
  max_evals: 10
}

eval_input_reader: {
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: 'data/test.record'
  }
  label_map_path: 'data/side_vehicle.pbtxt'
  shuffle: false
  num_readers: 1
}
```

**Why the time stamp of the model file does not change？Where is wrong?**

When I use this command to train:

> python model_main.py
>   --pipeline_config_path=training/ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco.config --model_dir=training/  --num_train_steps=10000

The error message is:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "E:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py",
>   line 1334, in _do_call
>       return fn(*args)   File "E:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py",
>   line 1319, in _run_fn
>       options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, run_metadata)   File "E:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py",
>   line 1407, in _call_tf_sessionrun
>       run_metadata) tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError:
>   assertion failed: [maximum box coordinate value is larger than
>   1.100000: ] [1.11401868]
>            [[{{node ToAbsoluteCoordinates_1/Assert/AssertGuard/Assert}} = Assert[T=[DT_STRING, DT_FLOAT], summarize=3, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](ToAbsoluteCoordinates_1/Assert/AssertGuard/Assert/Switch,
>   ToAbsoluteCoordina tes_1/Assert/AssertGuard/Assert/data_0,
>   ToAbsoluteCoordinates_1/Assert/AssertGuard/Assert/Switch_1)]]

Comment: you set the number of steps num_steps to be 100. so it created a checkpoint at 100th step. how ever time you run(without deleting the checkpoint file in the mentioned location) it assumes training is done already. try increasing the num_steps.

Comment: @venkatakrishnan
I've changed the num_train_steps=10000，but the error message changed，I have updated in my post.

Comment: this error is something to do with your bounding box, check all the bounding box dimensions are within range, i.e. within width and height of the image. it didnt throw this error earlier because, in the first 100 steps it didnt pass through the box which had error.

Comment: @venkatakrishnan
You mean I should check train.csv?
In my train.csv,the content likes this:
filename width height class xmin ymin xmax ymax
1.jpg 1138 677 side 127 560 340 594
2.jpg 1138 677 side 339 561 549 595
3.jpg 1138 677 side 548 562 759 597
4.jpg 1138 677 side 758 564 932 596
5.jpg 1166 697 side 75 528 273 565
6.jpg 1161 646 side 451 544 620 573

Comment: yes.basically your xml files with the bounding box. look for some github repository which provides python scripts to check bounding boxes.

Comment: @venkatakrishnan I have ckecked my train.csv and test.csv,the xmax of some data is equal to the width, can't it? Must xmax be smaller than the width?

Comment: preferably, considering the augmentations you do to the data also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I know where is wrong.My tensorflow's version is 1.9.0. I changed the version of tensorflow to 1.12.0, and then I modified this file `box_list_ops.py`,set `check_range=False`.So the problem was solved.